# Transfer request from one IIS 7 server to another

Tags: iis-7, state-management

Is there any way to configure IIS 7 to transfer a request to another server in a similar way to how the `Server.Transfer()` method works in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your comment under jsobo's answer:

> I have two servers, first server was
>   installed windows server 2008 and can
>   access from internet and second server
>   was installed windows server 2003 but
>   cannot access from internet. Unlucky
>   my website can only run on the second
>   server so I want to transfer request
>   from the first server to second
>   server. Do you have any suggestion for
>   me?

I think the IIS Application Request Routing module may be the answer here:

> [Application Request Routing module on IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting)

You could install this on your internet facing Windows 2008 server and have it route requests to and from the Windows 2003 server.

Comment: I think which I need to be "reverse proxy". I tried to use Application Request Routing but not successful, I found a solution it is URL Rewrite module. I use it to rewrite request URL by the URL points to windows 2003 server.
About Application Request Routing, it requires me to config a Web Farm but I don't know how to do. Does anybody instruct me? I did as follows Microsoft's tutorial but not success.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to actually do a response.redirect however if the request was a post and not a get then you have problems as the post data will be lost... your options are to proxy the request to the other server or to make a response to the client that writes an autoposting (via javascript) form.  Both options are a bit of a hack.

The question I have is why you want to transfer the request to another actual server.

Comment: I have two servers, first server was installed windows server 2008 and can access from internet and second server was installed windows server 2003 but cannot access from internet. Unlucky my website can only run on the second server so I want to transfer request from the first server to second server. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: it looks to me like you are trying to use IIS to be a proxy server... There are some situations where you might do that... like if you were adding functionality or security or modifying behavior bu tin the case it looks like you are simply trying to get the request from one server to the other. I would look at a reverse proxy server solution instead.  Squid is an example???

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do a transfer which silently redirects and then forgets, you want a proxy which handles the response as well.

Apache with mod_proxy can do this.

http://httpd.apache.org

A better choice though would be fixing the wacky setup.  Why can't the app that needs to access the internet not be on a computer that can access the internet?!?

Comment: Thank samuel, I will try as follows your suggestion. About my app, it cannot run on windows server 2008 which can access the internet.

Comment: @Linh, the best thing to do would be to fix the app so it can run on Windows Server 2008